# Scheme define-macro and/or define-syntax

Tags: macros, polymorphism, scheme, overloading

I want to create an overloaded Scheme macro for a simple form of polymorphism.  That is, a macro smart enough to expand differently when given params of different types, so that (look-up key container) does the "right" thing for different kinds of containers.

```
(define-macro (look-up key container)
  (cond
    ((table? container) `(table-ref ,key ,container))
    ((pair? container) `(assoc ,container ,key))
      etc.
    (else `(error "Unknown type to look-up))))
```

Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that Chris is right in that this is not really a job for macros.  A simple procedure might be what you're looking for:

```
(define (lookup key container)
  (cond ((type1? container)
           (type1-lookup key container))
         .                                 ; repeat for whichever types..
         .
        ((typeN? container)
           (typeN-lookup key container))
        (else 'undefined-lookup)))         ; or default value or ...
```

Or maybe you only need to find out what you're dealing with once so you can build build a more dedicated procedure on the fly.  Your `make-lookup` procedure might look very similar to the code above, except you would return a procedure, rather than call the lookup right away:

```
(define (make-lookup container)
  (cond ((type1? container)
           type1-lookup)
         .                                 ; repeat for supported types..
         .
        ((typeN? container)
           typeN-lookup)
        (else default-lookup-procedure)))

(define lookup (make-lookup container))
```

You could even add an optional argument to `make-lookup` that would take a procedure and use that rather than one of the type-specific lookups that you previously defined.

Comment: Thank you.  My plan was to eliminate the container-type testing at runtime for higher performance; these procedures are going to be called lots of times.  I was trying for a compile-time container type resolution, but I understand now about macro-expansion time versus compilation time.  Your suggestions have pointed me in a much better direction.  Thanks again.

Comment: @Brengle -- No problem.  How are you getting this data?  Is it a random assortment of different structures, or more like sets of the same type?

Comment: it is much more like large sets of the same type; lots of records from a couple of SQL tables.

Answer (score 2):

Macros are compile-time, not run-time. So you won't be able to query whether `container` is a table or pair or what not at macro-expansion time. You'd have to use a procedure to do that.

So, why not just use a procedure?